# Loop to print odd numbers not printing as many as it should

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that prints out a user-provided amount of odd numbers starting from a user-provided number.

So for an example if you would enter that you want to print out 5 numbers starting from the number 3, it would output 3, 5, 7, 9, and 11.

I'm currently trying to use the following code:

```
echo "Enter how many numbers you want to print"
read n
echo "Enter the first number"
read a

for ((a; a < n; a++)); do
  ((b = a % 2))
  if [ $b -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "$a"
  fi
done
```

However, with `n=5; a=3`, the output is not the expected `3` `5` `7` `9` `11` but is instead only `3`.

Comment: ...so, what's the part that doesn't actually work? See [mcve] guidelines -- a question should have a *specific problem* (not the larger problem your script tries to solve, but the problem *with your script*), and *the shortest code that lets others see that problem*.

Comment: BTW, a good place to start is logging with `set -x`. See your code running at https://ideone.com/hgCZDP, with a log in the "stderr" section.

Comment: ...in the current case, what you have isn't a bash-the-language bug, but a thinking-about-your-problem bug: You're comparing `a < n`, but `a` doesn't start at 0, it starts at the value the user entered, so it doesn't print `n` numbers; instead, it just prints odd numbers greater than or equal to `a` and less than `n`. For the examples `n=5` and `a=3`, the only odd number that meets that criteria is `3`, so that's all it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logic error, rather than a problem using bash. If you want to print `n` numbers, the easiest way to make sure that happens is to iterate from `0` to `n`, as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
n=5; a=3                   # of course, you can also read from the user.

if ((a % 2 == 0)); then    # if our starting number is even...
  (( ++a ))                # add 1 to make it odd.
fi

for ((i=0; i<n; i++)); do  # iterate from 0 to n...
  echo "$((a + i*2))"      # ...emitting 2*i+a each time.
done
```